# Get POST arguments from HttpRequestData using Content-Type multipart/form-data in .NET 5 Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, mime-types, .net-5

I am writing Azure functions and need to be able to pull the named arguments from a POST request body. Nevertheless, it has not been very straightforward and official examples or documents never show this. I have implemented my own solution, but it has not been working well for me.

The following NuGet Packages are required to test the code below:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

The farthest I have gotten is the following:

```
/* Azure Function, HTTP Trigger, .NET 5 : Update.cs */
[Function("Update")]
public static Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")]
        HttpRequestData req,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    //Get body of request
    StreamContent contentStream = new StreamContent(req.Body);
        
    //Get POST agruments out of multipart/form-data body into a dictionary
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    {
        MultipartMemoryStreamProvider multipart = await stream.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
        for (int i = 0; i < multipart.Contents.Count; i++)
        {
            NameValueCollection collection = await multipart.Contents[i].ReadAsFormDataAsync();
            foreach (string key in collection.Keys) dictionary.Add(key, collection[key]);
        }
    }
    //Exception thrown in last logical unit!
    contentStream.Dispose();
    return result;
}
```

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a content-type header value. 'HttpContent' instances must have a content-type header starting with 'multipart/'. (Parameter 'content')
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.Parsers.MimeMultipartBodyPartParser.ValidateArguments(HttpContent content, Int64 maxMessageSize, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.Parsers.MimeMultipartBodyPartParser..ctor(HttpContent content, MultipartStreamProvider streamProvider, Int64 maxMessageSize, Int32 maxBodyPartHeaderSize)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.Parsers.MimeMultipartBodyPartParser..ctor(HttpContent content, MultipartStreamProvider streamProvider)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.ReadAsMultipartAsync[T](HttpContent content, T streamProvider, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I do not understand why this exception is being thrown as watching the value of the req variable in a debugger reveals the following item in the Headers property:

```
multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------4784986464564849849262
```

I am open to a fix to my code, having another solution instead, or a point in the right direction.

Comment: What is your payload ? Is that a JSON ?

Comment: The payload is multipart/form, here is an example of that mime-type of payload: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#example

Answer (score 2):

just read body as text and then process it as necessary (e.g. convert to json):

```
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.Body);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```